# How can I make cookies in my Flash application?

Tags: flash, cookies, actionscript-2

How can I make cookies in my Flash application using ActionScript 2.0?

Comment: +1 for a nice question, actually I'd never even thought about getting cookies with Flash. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use JavaScript to work with cookies. You can do so from ActionScript using the [ExternalInterface API](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/8/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00002200.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you just need local storage and don't have a specific need for cookies Flash has it's own flavour of cookies called [SharedObjects](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/8/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00002661.html). 
They work more or less the same but they're only readable from Flash, they will however save you the bother of interfacing with javascript.

Comment: Yes for most uses this is the best way to go - they even work cross-browser I think.

Answer (score 0):

In AS2, I would say just create a javascript function to set the cookie and call it from within flash using a geturl request.

```
// Javascript Function
function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+
    ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
}

// AS2 Function
myBtn_btn.onRelease = function(){
 getURL("javascript:setCookie('my_cookie','my_value','30')");
};
```

Hope that helps.
chews

p.s. that is untested code but it should work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Flash ActionScript as own Cookies Mechanism which called Local Shared Object. you can use Local Shared Object as a cookies and when you will load once again same application you will find out the same data which stored in previous loaded application session.